# Java Graphics.drawString() freezes JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I am making my first java game, a space invaders clone. Everything is working as expected, except when I try to use the function Graphics.drawString(). It freezes the screen (JFrame)for about 3 or 4 seconds, before actually displaying the text. Is this a common problem or is it just on my end?

Comment: @see [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)  BTW ~ Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `is it just on my end?` - it is your code and the drawstring() has nothing to do with it. You are probably using Thread.sleep() somewhere which is causing the problem. .

Comment: DrawString's been working just fine for me for over 15 years, so it must be the way you're using it